# Obtaining column values for a dataframe from another dataframe based on a common column variable

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:
`df1 = pd.DataFrame({"animal": [Cat, Dog, Rat, Bull, Dog, Bull, Bull, Dog, Cat, Rat, Dog], "lifeSpan": [2, 4, 6, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 2, 6, 4]})`

`df2 = pd.Dataframe({"animal":[Bull, Cat, Rat, Dog]})`
The "LifeSpan" value is unique to each i in df1["animal"]. I need a third dataframe that mentions the "lifeSpan" value in a separate column against each j in df2["animal"] based on the 'lifespan' values in df1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to combine the two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"animal": ["Cat", "Dog", "Rat", "Bull", "Dog", "Bull", "Bull", "Dog", "Cat", "Rat", "Dog"], "lifeSpan": [2, 4, 6, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 2, 6, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"animal":["Bull", "Cat", "Rat", "Dog"]})

df3 = df2.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(), on="animal")
```

This returns the following dataframe:

| animal | lifeSpan |
| --- | --- |
| Bull | 0 |
| Cat | 2 |
| Rat | 6 |
| Dog | 4 |